# Problem with design of existing code (initialization of actions to perform)

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, coding-style, refactoring, clean-architecture

I have architectural problem with existing code and am looking for a clean-code solution.
I cannot show real code, but will show analogy.

Let's suppose that we have a car repair workshop. There are orders which can contain one or any number of actions (from known set) to perform. When worker is free, he execute operations according to current order.

But there's one main limitation: for some reasons Worker must have method PerformRepair( ) (this interface cannot be modified) and all operations should be executed on its call.

Now I have class RepairConfiguration, representing order with boolean values for all possible actions (bool ShouldChangeTyres, bool ShouldChangeEngineOil, bool ShouldRepairBrakes etc.). Worker is initialized with this RepairConfiguration. And when he PerformRepair( ), he checks each boolean and perform action if it's needed.

It look like this:

```java
//cannot be modified
public interface IWorker
{
    void PerformRepair( );
}

//worker implementation and all below CAN be modified
public class Worker : IWorker
{
    RepairConfiguration _repairConfiguration;
    AssignRepairConfiguration( RepairConfiguration config ) { _repairConfiguration = config; }
    PerformRepair( )
    {
        if( _repairConfiguration.ShouldChangeEngineOil )
            ChangeOil( );
        if( _repairConfiguration.ShouldRepairBrakes )
            RepairBrakes( );
        if( _repairConfiguration.ShouldChangeRim || _repairConfiguration.ShouldChangeTyres )
            TakeOffWheels( ); //some preparatory - common for a few actions
        if( _repairConfiguration.ShouldChangeTyres )
            ChangeTyres( );
        if( _repairConfiguration.ShouldChangeRim )
            ChangeRim( );
    //...... other conditions checking and actions
    }
      //implementation of all actions
}

public class RepairConfiguration
{
    bool ShouldChangeTyres;
    bool ShouldChangeEngineOil;
    bool ShouldRepairBrakes;
    bool ShouldChangeRim;
    //...... other bool conditions
}
```

As you can see, Worker implementation don't look good. There are a lot of IFs. And even if one action should be executed all conditions are checked. It also doesn't follow open/closed principle - when there is new possible action I need modify RepairConfiguration and Worker implementations. I wanted to ask you: how would you implement that? Are there any design patterns which could be helpful?

Comment: Can actions like  ChangeOil( ), RepairBrakes( ) etc. implement same interface? Also do you use RepairConfiguration anywhere else? How do you initialize RepairConfiguration fields?

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me that there is another problem that your analogy hides: a given unit of work consists of a set jobs to be performed, but is it necessarily true that every worker is capable of performing every job?

What I am getting at is an optimisation problem between what needs to be done, and the resources available to perform the work.   The most interesting bit gets into the condition where Worker=Diva can do everything but wants $1k/hr; but Workers=Tom,Dick,Harry together can do everything but each wants $100/hr.  This is *the scheduling problem*.

I don't know that blowing-up your problem helps with a solution, but there are very inefficient solutions to the above problems in most comp-sci books.  For sufficiently small numbers of N, inefficiency is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The command pattern could be a good solution. It allows the logic for each type of repair to be encapsulated in its own class, so that to change the logic for one type of repair, you only have to change one class. It also allows new repair types to be added simply by implementing the new IWorker subclass and modifying the factory - in other words, the calling class (RepairShop) doesn't need to change.

It might look something like this:

```
public interface IWorker
{
    void PerformRepair( );
}


public class OilChangeTechnician extends IWorker {
    public void PerformRepair() {
        //Logic to change oil
    }
}

public class TyreTechnician extends IWorker {
    public void PerformRepair() {
        //Logic to change tyres
    }
}

public class BrakeTechnician extends IWorker {
    public void PerformRepair() {
        //Logic to change brakes
    }
}

public class WorkerFactory extends AbstractWorkerFactory
{
    public CreateWorker(String repairType) {
        switch ("TyreChange"):
            return new TyreTechnician();
        switch ("BrakeChange"):
            return new BrakeTechnician();
        switch ("OilChange"):
            return new OilChangeTechnician();
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Unknown repairType: " + repairType);
    }
}


public class RepairShop {
    AbstractWorkerFactory workerFactory; //Inject this dependency
    public PerformRepairs(String args[]) {
        for (String repairType : args) {
            IWorker worker = workerFactory.CreateWorker(repairType);
            workers.PerformRepair();
        }
    }
}
```

The consumer would do something like this:

```
repairShop.performRepairs(new String[] {"TyreChange","BrakeChange"});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, one repair order can contain a few repairTypes (for example tyrechange + oilchange) or even all. And as I understand your solution is adapted for situation where one repair = exactly one repair type.

Comment: I made an edit to RepairShop class in the answer. Now it handles and arbitrary number of repairs per visit.